# Where is the memoization?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I am learning Kotlin and from the book, I have the fibonacci function, that demonstrates memoization concept:

```
import java.math.BigInteger

fun <T> List<T>.head(): T =
    if (this.isEmpty())
        throw IllegalArgumentException("head called on empty list")
    else
        this[0]

fun <T> List<T>.tail(): List<T> =
    if (this.isEmpty())
        throw IllegalArgumentException("tail called on empty list")
    else
        this.subList(1, this.size)

fun <T, U> foldLeft(list: List<T>, z: U, f: (U, T) -> U): U {
    tailrec fun foldLeft(list: List<T>, acc: U, f: (U, T) -> U): U =
        if (list.isEmpty())
            acc
        else
            foldLeft(list.tail(), f(acc, list.head()), f)
    return foldLeft(list, z, f)
}

fun fibo(number: Int): String {
    tailrec fun fibo(
        acc: List<BigInteger>, acc1: BigInteger,
        acc2: BigInteger, x: BigInteger
    ): List<BigInteger> =
        when (x) {
            BigInteger.ZERO -> acc
            BigInteger.ONE -> acc + (acc1 + acc2)
            else -> fibo(
                acc + (acc1 + acc2), acc2, acc1 + acc2,
                x - BigInteger.ONE
            )
        }

    val list = fibo(
        listOf(),
        BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.valueOf(number.toLong())
    )
    return makeString(list, ", ")
}

fun <T> makeString(list: List<T>, separator: String): String =
    when {
        list.isEmpty() -> ""
        list.tail().isEmpty() -> list.head().toString()
        else -> list.head().toString() +
                foldLeft(list.tail(), "") { x, y -> x + separator + y }
    }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println(fibo(5))

}
```

Could someone explain it to me, where is memoization here?

Answer (score 1):

I... don't think there is any, actually.

What I wanted to write initially is that the `acc` parameter of the helper `fibo` function (the one with 4 parameters marked by `tailrec`) ends up containing the previous Fibonacci numbers, but it isn't actually accessed to retrieve them, so I don't think it counts.

Here is what I would consider memoization in this style (note: I made `x` an `Int` because it simplifies code and you won't calculate a Fibonacci number with index not fitting into a `Long` in sane time even with memoization):

```
fun fibo(x: Int): BigInteger {
    tailrec fun fibo(
        acc: List<BigInteger>, x: Int
    ): Pair<List<BigInteger>, BigInteger> =
        when {
            x < acc.size -> Pair(acc, acc[x])
            x == acc.size -> {
                val y = acc[x - 1] + acc[x - 2]
                Pair(acc + y, y)
            }
            else ->
                fibo(fibo(fibo(acc, x - 2).first, x - 1).first, x)
        }

    return fibo(listOf(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE), x).second
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it a bit and make memoization (think a memo/note to remind you of something. Sort of like a cache.) a bit more explicit by doing something like this:

```
fun fib(n: Int, memo: MutableMap<Int, BigInteger> = mutableMapOf()): BigInteger {
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) return memo[n]!!
    if (n <= 2) return BigInteger.ONE
    memo[n] = fib(n - 1, memo) + fib(n - 2, memo)
    return memo[n]!!
}
```

You can see memoization in action here as each iteration stores the position and value of each number in the sequence. And within each fib call, we first check to see if the value already exists before creating another node in the call stack (think of each subsequent recursive call as creating a set of branching nodes until n is 1 or 2).

This is lightning fast, yielding linear O(n) time and space complexity even for cases like finding the 1000th number in the sequence. As opposed to O(2^n) without memoization.

First saw algorithm here and ported to kotlin: https://youtu.be/oBt53YbR9Kk